# In debug mode, the dynamically generated script file doesn't reflect saved changes

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In VS 2010, I have an asp.net web application project.  I made a change to a java-script file and saved it.  I then run the application in debug mode and looked at the corresponding dynamically generated java script file. The dynamically generated file still represents the code before i made the recent changes.  I tried restarting VS and my computer to no avail... This issue just started happening for no apparent reason.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on solution, and click clean.